# livewire focus out phone number disappear for milliseconds

Tags: laravel, livewires

I am using Livewire, and I've encountered an issue where the phone number value disappears or reverts to the older value. To handle phone number input, I am utilizing the 'intl-tel-input' library.

I must ensure that it does not disappear or retain the older value.

Comment: [`intl-tel-input`](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) this one? its hard to come up with anything given no relevant snippet is seen. if you haven't you should take a [tour] and learn [ask] - its also best to provide [mcve].